# Implementing Ajax/Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

OK, I am going to preface this with the warning that my code skills are really rudimentary--I've cobbled together what I can, but my lack of experience with Javascript is keeping me from implementing this final thing. I have my page set up: http://excitable.media/reddit.php

It is almost doing what I want. The arrows are changing on click with the CSS. The Big number is being called from an SQL Database, in a table named `votes` that has only one column--`count`. What I want to happen now is that when someone clicks the up arrow, the count entry is increased by one and the vote count on the page is updated. I know I need AJAX/JQuery to do this, but once again, even the syntax is difficult for me. Here is the page code right now:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Reddit</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css/reddit.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/js/reddit.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>reddit</h1>

<div class="container">
<div class="up">
<input id="img-switcher" type="checkbox"></input>
<label for="img-switcher"></label>
</div>
<div class="count" id="vote-value">
<?php
include '../php/config.php';
$con;
$dbhandle;
$selected;
if($vote)
echo $vote[0];
?>
</div>
<div class="essay">
<p>Registering an account with Reddit [paragraph text omitted]</p>
</div>
<div="down">
<input id="img-switcher-2" type="checkbox"></input>
<label for="img-switcher-2"></label>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me with this rudimentary coding project? I have another php file called 'insert.php' that connects to the database and then says:

```
$update=mysql_query("UPDATE 'votes' SET 'count'='count'+1)");
if(mysql_query($update)){
    return "success!";
}
else {
    return "failed!";
}
```

The reddit.js file is totally empty right now, it's where I am expecting to place the code to make this work. It's also worth mentioning that I don't care about the down arrow at all. I don't want it to function. I only want the up arrow to work. I don't care if people click it more than once from the same IP.

Comment: `mysql_query` is a deprecated function. If you are still learning, this is an excellent time to learn about it's replacement.

Comment: And I think you used the wrong quotes in the update statement. The normal single quotes are for strings, not to enclose identifiers.

Comment: That query will never work. `'votes'` is a string. You want `\`votes\``.

Comment: And you actually do not need to escape column or table names unless you are using reserved keywords ;)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you should change your mysql code. As for the js, you could do something like this:

```
var blocked = false; // if we are waiting for a server response, we need to block up arrow click
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".up").click(function(){ // on click
        if(blocked == false){ // if we are not waiting a server response
            blocked = true; // we are waiting a server response
            $.ajax({ //make ajax
                url: "insert.php"
            }).success(function(msg){ 
                if(msg == "success!"){ // if it was success, add 1 to our local count
                    $(".count").text(Number($(".count").text()) +1)
                }else{
                    console.log(msg)
                }
                blocked = false; // allow up arrow click again
            }).fail(function(){
                console.log("failed")
                blocked = false;// allow up arrow click again
            })
        }        
    })
})
```

Note: It would be even better to return new count from server in case 2 or more different users update the counter, in that case the local page would show incorrect count

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a ajax event which will send the request to database and get data from database the query would be some thing like below:

```
$("button").click(function(){
   $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
    $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
 });
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp
and secondly your update query is wrong kindly check it again

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who posted help--this has been a long process but I FINALLY got it working. I did some JQuery, SQL, and PHP tutorials, and greatly improved the code...the ultimate culprit that bogged me down ended up being file paths to files outside the root!

For the Javascript, simple $.get and $.post commands were more than enough. I ended up splitting it into one function to load the count initially, and one count to update/change the count, each referencing a different php file:

```
$.get('/css/js/fetch.php', function(data) {
        $('.count').html(data);
});
```

and

```
$('#up').click(function(){
    $.post('/css/php/insert.php', function(data) {
        $('.count').html(data);
    });
});
```

The other thing that bogged me down (if anyone ever searches for the same problem and reads this), was how exactly information gets from the PHP file to the Javascript. In fetch.php (for the initial display), I wrote:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM votes WHERE id = 1");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo $row["VoteCount"];
}
```

The "key", I guess, was using echo to create an output that the Javascript then just grabs (I was looking at json_encode, but I guess that was more complex than I needed)